# navigation property not loading in "Entity Keys" scenario with Conversion

Tags: c#, entity-framework, domain-driven-design

I try to config "Entity Keys" scenario with Conversion like this:

```
{
    var ScoringRuleConverter = new ValueConverter<ScoringRuleId, int>(
         v => v.Value,
         v => new ScoringRuleId(v));

    var ScoringRuleItemIdConverter = new ValueConverter<ScoringRuleItemId, int>(
          v => v.Value,
          v => new ScoringRuleItemId(v));

    builder.HasKey(c => c.Id);
    builder.Property(c => c.ScoringRuleId).HasConversion(ScoringRuleConverter);
    builder.Property(c => c.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();
           
    builder.OwnsMany(h => h.ScoringRuleItems, mi =>
            {
                mi.WithOwner().HasForeignKey(d => d.ScoringRuleId);
                mi.HasKey(d => d.Id);
                mi.Property(m => m.ScoringRuleItemId).HasConversion(ScoringRuleItemIdConverter);
                mi.Property(m => m.ScoringRuleItemId).ValueGeneratedNever();
                mi.Property(m => m.ScoringRuleId).HasConversion(ScoringRuleConverter);
               
                mi.OwnsMany(h => h.ScoringRuleItemHistories, mih =>
                {                    
                    mih.WithOwner().HasForeignKey(d => d.ScoringRuleItemId);
                    mih.HasKey(d => d.ScoringRuleItemHistoryId);
                    mih.Property(m => m.ScoringRuleItemHistoryId).HasConversion(ScoringRuleItemHistoryId=> ScoringRuleItemHistoryId.Value, value => new ScoringRuleItemHistoryId(value));
                    mih.Property(m => m.ScoringRuleItemHistoryId).ValueGeneratedNever();
                    mih.Property(m => m.ScoringRuleItemId).HasConversion(ScoringRuleItemIdConverter);
                });
            });
}
```

With these model classes:

```
public class ScoringRule : Entity
{
    public ScoringRuleId Id { get; private set; }

    //.....
       
    private readonly ICollection<ScoringRuleItem> _ScoringRuleItems = new List<ScoringRuleItem>();

    public IReadOnlyCollection<ScoringRuleItem> ScoringRuleItems  => _ScoringRuleItems.ToList();

    private ScoringRule() { }

    private ScoringRule(string title, ScoringRuleType scoringRuleType)
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        // ....
    }
}

public class ScoringRuleItem
{
    public ScoringRuleItemID Id { get; private set; }   
    public ScoringRuleId ScoringRuleId { get; set; }

    private ICollection<ScoringRuleItemHistory> _scoringRuleItemHistories=new List<ScoringRuleItemHistory>();
    public IReadOnlyCollection<ScoringRuleItemHistory> ScoringRuleItemHistories => _scoringRuleItemHistories.ToList();

    private ScoringRuleItem() { }

    protected internal ScoringRuleItem(Guid scoringRuleId, decimal maxAmount, string userId)
    {
        //....
    }
}
```

Insert entity works ok, but in get list of `ScoringRule` with `Items`, EF remains in loading mode!

I tried with separate config for entity, but I still get the same result.

- VS 2022 (Version 17.6.5)
- `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` 7.0.9
- .NET 7